# Check previous row's value with another row inside the loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of at least 100 rows from my DB. Each row has to be checked with each other.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM goods ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->()){
      
     $product_name = $row['product'];
     $product_price = $row['price'];
     
     //something like:
     if($row['price'] > $row['price']){
      $color = 'red';
     }else($row['price'] < $row['price']){
      $color = 'black';
     }
     
     echo "
       <div><span style='color:$color;'>Price: $poduct_price</span>Product: $product_name</div>
     ";
     

   }

}else{
   echo "0 results";
}
```

I tried to implement foreach loop but can't figure out how to check each row. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the previous row in another variable and compare with that.

```
$prev_row = null;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $product_name = $row['product'];
    $product_price = $row['price'];

    if ($prev_row && $product_price > $prev_row['price']) {
        $color = 'red';
    } else {
        $color = 'black';
    }
    echo "
<div><span style='color:$color;'>Price: $product_price</span>Product: $product_name</div>
";
    $prev_row = $row;
}
```